# How to print customize logging in Crashlytics Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

We have install pod file for fabric and crashlytics and imported in the app delegate. **Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Branch.self])** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function. It's working fine. But I want to print which action could be clicked by the user. **Eg) Clicked Login** Button.

I saw we can call  this function, But where can i call this?

```
func write(string: String) {
        CLSLogv("%@", getVaList([string]))
    }
```

we won't be able to find the line of code from this crash

How to print custom logs in fabric? 
Which default function get called while getting crash?

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/answers/manual-install?step=3

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/answers/features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `CrashLogger` class with logEvent function which takes eventName as `String` and data dictionary which is `[String: CustomStringConvertible]` format to pass any relevant info to Crashlytics

```
import Crashlytics

final class CrashLogger {

    static let shared = CrashLogger()

    private init() { }

    func logEvent(_ event: String, withData data: [String: CustomStringConvertible]) {
        let dataString = data.reduce("Event: \(event): ", { (result, element: (key: String, value: CustomStringConvertible)) -> String in
            return result + " (" + element.key + ": " + String(describing: element.value) + " )"
        })
        logEvent(dataString)
    }

    private func logEvent(_ message: String) {
        CLSLogv("%@", getVaList([message]))
    }
}
```

Now you can call this `logEvent` method whenever you want to log the custom event in Crashlytics and it will be available in logs section when you view any crash in Firebase.

**How to use:** for example `addToCart` function in eCommerce application:

```
func addToCard(_ product: Product) {
    CrashLogger.logEvent("addToCart", withData: ["productId": product.id, "productName": product.name)
    //do further processing like update cart item count etc.
}
```

Refer Crashlytics custom logging [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

You can log custom activities via `.recordError(NSERROR)` below code. However, I don't recommend you to use Crashlytics for these kind of "Button Clicked" logs. Use some Analytics tools like (Google Analytics).

```
let customError = NSError(domain: errorDomain, code: errorCode, userInfo: [
            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message,
            ])
            Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(customError)
```

Comment: But where can I call this?

Comment: In your button tap function.

Comment: Yes. But I have to use a common function for crash. I have more than 50 Buttons in my app.