# NSRangeException by String.subscript.getter

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this `mid` method in `Extension`.

```
func mid(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) -> String {

    var _fromIndex = 0

    if( fromIndex >= self.count ) {
        return ""
    }
    else if( fromIndex > 0 ){
        _fromIndex = fromIndex
    }

    var _toIndex = 0

    if( toIndex >= self.count ) {
        _toIndex = self.count - 1
    }
    else if( toIndex > 0 ){
        _toIndex = toIndex
    }

    if( _fromIndex > _toIndex ){
        return ""
    }

    return String(self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: _fromIndex)...self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: _toIndex)])
}
```

And use this method to retrieve user deleted string.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    defer{
        if text.isEmpty {
            let deletedText = textView.attributedText.string.mid(fromIndex: range.lowerBound, toIndex: range.upperBound)
        }
    }
}
```

But it sometimes throws this exception.

`Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[NSBigMutableString characterAtIndex:]: Index 672 out of bounds; string length 672
specialized String.subscript.getter`

I already check the size of the string before using `String.subscript.getter`.

```
if( toIndex >= self.count ) {
    _toIndex = self.count - 1
}
```

And the text operation should be on the main thread.
Why am I still getting this exception?
Did I misunderstood the string index in Swift?

**UPDATE1**

According to @Wattholm's answer.
I'm using this way to get text with `NSRange` from `UITextView`.

```
let contents: String = textView.text

if let _range = Range(range, in: contents) {
    let deletedText = String(contents[_range])
}
else {
    logHelper.w("Failed to get deletedText from NSRange, try UITextRange.")

    if let startPosition = textView.position(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, offset: range.location),
       let endPosition = textView.position(from: startPosition, offset: range.length),
       let textRange = textView.textRange(from: startPosition, to: endPosition), 
       let deletedText = textView.text(in: textRange) {

        // do something with deletedText
    }
    else {
        logHelper.w("Failed to get deletedText from UITextRange, try NSString.")

        let deletedText = (contents as NSString).mid(fromIndex: range.lowerBound, toIndex: range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

But it still fall into the second `else` and throwing `NSRangeException`.
Which means the length and the index still doesn't match each other.

**UPDATE2**

Tried to use `NSString.substring` but still keep getting this exception.

```
let deletedText = (contents as NSString).substring(with: range)
```

Maybe there's a bug in UITextView?

Comment: `deletedText = contents.mid()` - did you mean `textView.text` instead of `contents`?

Comment: Also note the case where `toIndex` is `self.count + 17` for example.

Comment: [Swifter extensions](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift)?

Comment: @Yonat Sorry,  I forgot to mention that the contents is from `textView.attributedText.string`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give the string text in the textView when the error occurs, so I can replicate the error? And also I would like to know what the user does that triggers the call to ShouldChangeTextIn right before the NSRangeException occurs?  Might also if you could log some of the data to the console such as the lower bound, upper bound, contents, deletedText at that point.

Comment: Also, your last line of code (below the 2nd else) is slightly different from mine.  I subtract 1 from the upperBound since the upperBound itself should not be included in the ToIndex:  `let deletedText = (contents as NSString).mid(fromIndex: range.lowerBound, toIndex: range.upperBound - 1)`

Comment: @Wattholm The user deleted the last letter in the TextView, so I need to retrieve the deleted string. The `mid` method will check if the index is out of bounds. So it will still throw this exception even if we pass `range.upperBound - 1` to it. As you can see, I use `let _range = Range(range, in: contents)` first to get the deleted string. But it still fall into the second `else`. Which means the range is not matching the contents already. I just deployed a new version which is using `let deletedText = (contents as NSString).substring(with: range)` to test it.

Comment: @KimiChiu Thanks. Can you give an example of the actual raw STRING used that causes the error?  I have a barebones project that tests your case and it seems to return the deletedText without problems for ALL the strings that I have used as input to the textView. Deleting single characters and/or selections works as well, as far as my testing went. If I could reproduce the error on my end then I would be much closer to figuring out where we went wrong.

Comment: @Wattholm Sorry, I can't. I got this error report from Crashlytics. I have no idea what user inputed to the `TextView`. I have never reproduced this issue by myself. The only thing I know is my main users are using Traditional-Chinese. So the input method might be the problem.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Crashlytics but I think you may be able to log the data you need so you can access it in the reports that Crashlytics provides.  There's a post which outlines the basics of how to do it: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866781/how-to-print-customize-logging-in-crashlytics-swift`. . Also here's documentation for logging errors in Crashlytics from the Fabric site docs: `https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html`.

Comment: @KimiChiu did you manage to solve it? I have the same crash. With the same group of users. However, it only happens with iOS 12.x

Comment: I just have a workaround. `let contents: String = textView.text + "suffix"`. So it won't crash.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong but I think the issue here relates to the inherent differences between String and NSString, or between Range and NSRange.  A String's count will not always be the same as an NSString's length.

There might be an easier way to do it, but what I attempted was to create an extension for NSString in the same way that you created one for String, and then cast 'contents' (which I assume is a String; there seems to be some missing code here since 'contents' was not declared anywhere) to NSString so that it would work correctly, since the textview supplies us with the NSRange:

```
extension NSString {
    func mid(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) -> NSString {

        var _fromIndex = 0

        if( fromIndex >= self.length ) {
            return ""
        }
        else if( fromIndex > 0 ){
            _fromIndex = fromIndex
        }

        var _toIndex = 0

        if( toIndex >= self.length ) {
            _toIndex = self.length - 1
        }
        else if( toIndex > 0 ){
            _toIndex = toIndex
        }

        if( _fromIndex > _toIndex ){
            return ""
        }

        return NSString(string: self.substring(with: NSRange(location: _fromIndex, length: _toIndex - _fromIndex + 1)))
    }
}
```

And for the textview:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    defer{
        if text.isEmpty {
            let deletedText = (contents as NSString).mid(fromIndex: range.lowerBound, toIndex: range.upperBound - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

The other way to do this is to convert the NSRange into a Range, which is probably the better way, especially if you require that the count of characters be exactly the way a String counts its characters in Swift.  The range: NSRange in the textview function can be converted to a Range like this:

let swiftRange = Range(range, in: rangeText)

where rangeText should be replaced by the text property that the range is referring to.

Comment: The `contents` is from `textView.attributedText.string`. I've edited the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *swiftier* version which takes advantage of the reliable conversion from `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` and vice versa.

```
extension String {

    func mid(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) -> String {
        guard toIndex >= fromIndex else  { return "" }
        let nsRange = NSRange(location: fromIndex, length: toIndex + 1 - fromIndex)
        guard let range = Range(nsRange, in: self) else { return "" }
        return String(self[range])
    }
}
```

Actually you don't need the extension as you already got an `NSRange`, just write

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    defer{
        if text.isEmpty {
            let textViewString = textView.attributedText.string
            guard let swiftRange = Range(range, in: textViewString) else { return }
            let deletedText = String(textViewString[swiftRange])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already use `Range(range, in: textViewString)`  in my app. You can see this line in UPDATE1. But it still fall into the second `else`. Maybe the range is not matching the contents already?